# Fresh install 12.04 Performance & Stability: SONY VPCCW2S1E

Tags: performance, vaio, sony

just yesterday I installed 12.04 - 64bit.

Is it normal that installing a package (Chrome for example) takes 5 to 10 minutes (compared to Windows 7 for example which takes 2 or 3)? (with end result: installation failed)
Otherwise is it normal that while the system is doing some installation,extracting packs and so on, other applications often become unresponsive?

Sidenote: I don't care about fancy desktop effects, I installed ubuntu to go on and experiment with web servers, memcache, Varnish and git/svn. So basically I plan to do lots of console-only operations.

My surprise was also the difference of stability compared to an old FreeBSD installation I had on a dinosaur P3 550Mhz :)

(I am on a SONY VPCCW2S1E) (I guess it might have to do something with my problems?)

I noticed when doing 'top' that the process that is taking most of the CPU time, and that is pumping up randomly, is mount.ntfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found out that the fact that I installed Ubuntu on a partition of a NTFS drive might have to do with it. Here is what I found:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1653598

It seems that there is no clear solution besides dropping ntfs because of the driver which does not seem to work that well.

:(

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be a problem with a Wubi install on NTFS - that's how it's *supposed* to run.  Definitely something happening though - maybe the NTFS partition is badly fragmented?

Comment: While searching for 'mount.ntfs problem CPU' I saw that its quite a popular problem and ad wubi is concerned I was told to use it only for testing and to avoid it... I installed ubuntu on its own partition and its blazing fast.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not normal - according to the specs I looked at your machine is an i3 processor and only a few years old.  It should be running much better than this EeePC 900SD I am on at the moment which has no problem installing Chrome or anything else with it's 900Mhz Celeron.

Make sure you've run all the updates, and they any required third party drivers are loaded - video, network etc.

The first step in debugging this is finding out where the bottle neck really is.  Install and run top in command line to see what processes are are taking *all* of the cpu time. I also run Gkrellm system monitor at all times because it gives a good overview of cpu, disk, memory etc and gives a good idea what the machine is doing at any time.  Others prefer conky or similar applications for this.

Comment: I noticed when doing 'top' that the process that is taking most of the CPU time, and that is pumping up randomly, is mount.ntfs.

Comment: It's taking above 90% of my CPU when I do certain actions that mostly have to do with the Software center (like more info in a package, installing a new package, removing etc)

Comment: OK, well that's odd.  I think the next thing I'd do is comment the ntfs mounts out of /etc/fstab and reboot.  Running with just the required ext4 partitions mounted, does the system run better?  Maybe there's a problem with the NTFS partitions that is not being resolved nicely.

Comment: its ok, i had unstalled Ubuntu with WUBI and apparently thats not good.. .I re installed with a normal partition and its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not normal, try different distribution for example Xubuntu or Knopix 7.04.Check md5sum and record yours dvd in lower speed.